# How do I create a compiz launcher on the desktop?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, launcher

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 Beta 1, and I've noticed Compiz likes to crash, every now and then. I'd like to create a Compiz on my desktop, so if it does, I can run that to bring it back up. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Create a desktop launcher and for the command type in compiz --replace. This should restart compiz